# Model builder to call python script

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, model

So I'm looking to write a script that can be called by model builder.  What I would like this script to do is to select three records from a feature class that have the highest field values ('AverageGasPrice').  Basically, I want the script to select the three most expensive gas prices. I am not sure where to start, however.

Is there also a way to have the model launch and allow the user to enter which Feature Class they would like to specify as the input FC? If this is not possible, I will also require assistance with how to 'hardcode' the input file using relative path (everything will be stored in one file geodatabase).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select specific features with search cursors

http://help.arcgis.com/de/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000

and you can specifiy the input with GetParameterAsText

http://help.arcgis.com/de/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000014000000